# can't run openni_tracker

Tags: kinect, openi-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I folow the tutorial,the openni_camera tutorial can work.
But when I type rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker,it return

InitFromXml failed: Can't create any node of the requested type!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11031/can%27t-run-openni_tracker/) by [JosephChen](https://answers.ros.org/users/980/josephchen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-08-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a duplicate of [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/704/openni_tracker-initfromxml-failed-cant-create-any).

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2011-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1